# hg addremove in git

Tags: git, mercurial

I really need this command in git

```
hg addremove
```

So now look at scenario and see how mercurial would save me in here:

I had some kind of dir in here var/htdocs/static/static. I accidentally moved files to wrong location (with git-mv). anyway... now I moved some folders around by hand:

```
mv static static2
mv static2/static ./
```

Maybe I've changed some files in here too... and now everything is great... so now git doesn't know what happend? How he could trace a movement of files without notifying it like mercurial does with addremove.

For example now with mercurial I could do:

```
hg addremove --similarity 80%
```

that's it - mercurial traced where files was moved by recognizing files content, and I saved my files history.

one lad in [here](http://importantshock.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/git-vs-mercurial/) have some trick for this:

```
git add .
git ls-files --deleted | xargs git rm
```

but it's like in CVS back then. you deleting files, you adding files. what about saving history of files??

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Basically, git always automatically does something sort of like "addremove" when it applies a commit to update the working tree:  it looks at added and removed files in the commit and detects pairs of added and removed files that are probably renames (using a "amount of change" heuristic).  So you don't have to use a special command; just do the adds and the removes, and git will later figure things out on its own.

In your example scenario, just tell git about the new files: `git add static` and about the deleted files: `git add -u static`, and you're ready to commit.  If you do a `git status` before committing, you can see that it's already detected the rename.

[As another answer mentioned, `git add -A` is a nice shortcut that just adds *everything* in the working tree, including new and deleted files; the only reason to use the narrower commands above is if you want to avoid adding some other changes that happen to be in the working tree.]

Comment: finally somebody normally explained this =) thnx. I think lot's of users had this question.. nobody said nothing that things goes on behind the scene..

Comment: Thanks :)
BTW note that "git add -A" as another reply mentioned, is a nice shortcut if you don't have other changes lying around (I updated my answer to include that too).

Comment: I'm fairly certain that Git doesn't do rename detection on commit, but instead in post-commit analysis, as mentioned by Charles Bailey (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021063/hg-addremove-in-git#comment9817834_8021101).

Comment: @MaxNanasy You are right, but you seem to have misunderstood what I said (or was trying to say, anyway).  I didn't say git does "commit-time" rename detection, I said "git detects renames when it applies a commit to a working tree", i.e., "after the fact."  I think my wording is a little awkward technically, as git doesn't actually "apply commits"; I'll try to fix up the wording later to be more pre cise.

Answer (score 10):

Git doesn't track renames via additional metadata so you can just do `git add -A` with the full assurance that you aren't missing any metadata.

While Git tracks "whole tree" history rather than file history, you can activate its rename and copy detection after the fact with commands like `git log -M -C` and `git log --follow <file>`.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm dump today. could you edit what commands I should type instead of hg addremove to achieve my scenario? I've got like 5 commands instead of one (like in hg) this is extremely confusing me, so I just ask a little edition of your post with all quoted commands

Comment: @holms: If you mean the equivalent of `hg addremove`, then `git add -A`, like I said. git doesn't care about renames at `add` time so the `--similarity` is irrelevant for the translation from `hg` to `git`.

Comment: @holms: Note `git add -A` also stages changes to already tracked files. I'm not sure if `hg addremove` has this effect.

Comment: so you telling me that git add -A can track renames and all my history of files will be saved? =)

Comment: @holms: I'm saying that git doesn't track renames explicitly, however you add or remove files, so it doesn't matter how you do it. Any rename detection only happens after the fact.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: hg does not "stage".

Answer (score 8):

Short answer.  The command most similar to `hg addremove` in **git** is:

```
git add -A
```

Oooorr...

```
git add --all
```